# Ejecting USB devices on linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, dbus, udev

I'm using Udisks via dbus in python to unmount a usb device (in this case a Kindle), but I'd like to send the eject signal to it, as this kicks the Kindle back from USB mode into its usual interface.

Udisks won't let me DriveEject, as it's not an actual drive, and I gather this is a feature. The error given is:

```
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.UDisks.Error.Failed: Device is not a drive
```

The Udisks [documentation](http://hal.freedesktop.org/docs/udisks/udisks.7.html) mentions the ejectable property:

> ID_DRIVE_EJECTABLE
>
> Whether the media in the drive is
>   physically ejectable. Only set this to
>   1 (or 0) if the drive truly uses (or
>   doesn't) ejectable media. In
>   particular, it is not necessary to set
>   this for e.g. iPod or Kindle devices
>   where it is necessary to send a
>   command via eject(1) since the desktop
>   user session will offer this option
>   for removable devices regardless of
>   whether they are ejectable. If this
>   property is not set, a heuristic will
>   be used to determine if the media is
>   ejectable (drives using optical, Zip
>   or Jaz media are considered
>   ejectable).

but doesn't explain how to do this from the desktop user session.

(Nautilus lets me eject just fine from the desktop shell. The 'eject' shell command will unmount but won't send the eject signal to the device without sudo)

Is there any legitimate way to do this with Udisks, and if not, how does nautlius go about doing it?

Comment: I'd be tempted to have a browse through the Nautilus source code and/or configuration...

Comment: Whoever is voting to close: Clearly mark knows very well about Super User, as he has far more rep there than here.  It looks like he opened an account here specifically to be able to ask this question.  So I think it's safe to assume he's looking for a solution that requires some coding (mentions dbus in the question as well) and would be off-topic on SU.

Comment: @Ben Right, this is all being done via python, perhaps I didn't make that clear, but I assumed any solution using dbus would be language independent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it turns out I was trying to eject the partition, not the drive itself, hence the "Device is not a drive error". (Which is to say, calling udisks eject on /dev/sdc1 rather than /dev/sdc)

The solution was to first unmount the partition using FilesystemUnmount(), then find the parent drive using the "PartitionSlave" property, and call DriveEject() on this.

In python with dbus, assuming you already have a device object from Udisks for the parition, this looks something like:

```
dev_if = dbus.Interface(device_object, 'org.freedesktop.UDisks.Device')
dev_if.FilesystemUnmount([])
device_props = dbus.Interface(device_object, dbus.PROPERTIES_IFACE)
drive = device_props.Get('org.freedesktop.UDisks.Device', "PartitionSlave")
drive_obj = self.bus.get_object("org.freedesktop.UDisks", drive)
drive_if = dbus.Interface(drive_obj, 'org.freedesktop.UDisks.Device')
drive_if.DriveEject([])
```